# connection not getting established between hazelcast client and hazelcast server

Tags: hazelcast

The client and server configs for hazelcast v3.6 are copied below.  I can run the server (listening on 127.0.0.1:5706)

```
I get the following error on the hazelcast client side:
[warn] c.h.c.c.n.ClientConnection - Connection [/127.0.0.1:5701] lost. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException[null]
[warn] c.h.c.s.i.ClusterListenerSupport - Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 2986 ms later, attempt 1 of 2.
```

**hazelcast-client.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <hazelcast-client xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config hazelcast-client-config-3.6.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>

    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.shuffle.member.list">true</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout">60000</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.interval">5000</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.event.thread.count">5</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.event.queue.capacity">1000000</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.invocation.timeout.seconds">120</property>
    </properties>

    <network>
        <cluster-members>
            <address>127.0.0.1:5701</address>
          <!--  <address>0.0.0.0</address>  -->
        </cluster-members>
        <smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
        <redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
        <connection-timeout>60000</connection-timeout>
        <connection-attempt-period>3000</connection-attempt-period>
        <connection-attempt-limit>2</connection-attempt-limit>
        <socket-options>
            <tcp-no-delay>false</tcp-no-delay>
            <keep-alive>true</keep-alive>
            <reuse-address>true</reuse-address>
            <linger-seconds>3</linger-seconds>
            <timeout>-1</timeout>
            <buffer-size>32</buffer-size>
        </socket-options>

        <socket-interceptor enabled="false">
            <class-name>com.hazelcast.examples.MySocketInterceptor</class-name>
            <properties>
                <property name="foo">bar</property>
            </properties>
        </socket-interceptor>

        <ssl enabled="false">
            <factory-class-name>com.hazelcast.examples.MySslFactory</factory-class-name>
        </ssl>

        <aws enabled="false" connection-timeout-seconds="11">
            <inside-aws>true</inside-aws>
            <access-key>TEST_ACCESS_KEY</access-key>
            <secret-key>TEST_SECRET_KEY</secret-key>
            <region>us-east-1</region>
            <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
            <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
            <tag-key>type</tag-key>
            <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
        </aws>

    </network>

    <executor-pool-size>40</executor-pool-size>  <!-- reduce the pool size after profiling -->


    <security>
        <credentials>com.hazelcast.security.UsernamePasswordCredentials</credentials>
    </security>

    <listeners>
        <!--<listener>com.hazelcast.examples.MembershipListener</listener>
        <listener>com.hazelcast.examples.InstanceListener</listener>
        <listener>com.hazelcast.examples.MigrationListener</listener>
        -->
    </listeners>

    <!-- change to kryo -->
 <!--   <serialization>
        <portable-version>3</portable-version>
        <use-native-byte-order>true</use-native-byte-order>
        <byte-order>BIG_ENDIAN</byte-order>
        <enable-compression>false</enable-compression>
        <enable-shared-object>true</enable-shared-object>
        <allow-unsafe>false</allow-unsafe>
        <data-serializable-factories>
            <data-serializable-factory factory-id="1">com.hazelcast.examples.DataSerializableFactory
            </data-serializable-factory>
        </data-serializable-factories>
        <portable-factories>
            <portable-factory factory-id="2">com.hazelcast.examples.PortableFactory</portable-factory>
        </portable-factories>
        <serializers>
            <global-serializer>com.hazelcast.examples.GlobalSerializerFactory</global-serializer>
            <serializer type-class="com.hazelcast.examples.DummyType"
                        class-name="com.hazelcast.examples.SerializerFactory"/>
        </serializers>
        <check-class-def-errors>true</check-class-def-errors>
    </serialization>

-->


    <native-memory enabled="false" allocator-type="POOLED">
        <size unit="MEGABYTES" value="128" />
        <min-block-size>1</min-block-size>
        <page-size>1</page-size>
        <metadata-space-percentage>40.5</metadata-space-percentage>
    </native-memory>

    <!--
    <proxy-factories>
        <proxy-factory class-name="com.hazelcast.examples.ProxyXYZ1" service="sampleService1"/>
        <proxy-factory class-name="com.hazelcast.examples.ProxyXYZ2" service="sampleService1"/>
        <proxy-factory class-name="com.hazelcast.examples.ProxyXYZ3" service="sampleService3"/>
    </proxy-factories>
-->
    <load-balancer type="random"/>

    <!--
        Beware that near-cache eviction configuration is different for NATIVE in-memory format.
        Proper eviction configuration example for NATIVE in-memory format :
           `<eviction max-size-policy="USED_NATIVE_MEMORY_SIZE" eviction-policy="LFU" size="60"/>`
    -->

 <!--   <near-cache name="default">
        <max-size>2000</max-size>
        <time-to-live-seconds>90</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>100</max-idle-seconds>
        <eviction-policy>LFU</eviction-policy>
        <invalidate-on-change>true</invalidate-on-change>
        <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
        <local-update-policy>INVALIDATE</local-update-policy>
    </near-cache>
-->
    <!--
    <query-caches>
        <query-cache name="query-cache-name" mapName="map-name">
            <predicate type="class-name">com.hazelcast.examples.ExamplePredicate</predicate>
            <entry-listeners>
                <entry-listener include-value="true" local="false">com.hazelcast.examples.EntryListener</entry-listener>
            </entry-listeners>
            <include-value>true</include-value>
            <batch-size>1</batch-size>
            <buffer-size>16</buffer-size>
            <delay-seconds>0</delay-seconds>
            <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
            <coalesce>false</coalesce>
            <populate>true</populate>
            <eviction eviction-policy="LRU" max-size-policy="ENTRY_COUNT" size="10000"/>
            <indexes>
                <index ordered="false">name</index>
            </indexes>
        </query-cache>
    </query-caches>
-->

</hazelcast-client>
```

**hazelcast server**

here is the console message on the server and server config file:

**console message**

```
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Established socket connection between /127.0.1.1:5701 and /127.0.0.1:47301
Mar 10, 2016 12:01:48 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Connection [/127.0.0.1:47301] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]
```

**hazelcast.xml (server)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.6.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>

    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <ports>0-5900</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <!--<multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>-->
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <member>127.0.0.1</member>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="true">
            <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
        </interfaces>
        <ssl enabled="false" />
        <socket-interceptor enabled="false" />
        <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
            <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
            <!-- salt value to use when generating the secret key -->
            <salt>thesalt</salt>
            <!-- pass phrase to use when generating the secret key -->
            <password>thepass</password>
            <!-- iteration count to use when generating the secret key -->
            <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
        </symmetric-encryption>
    </network>

    <partition-group enabled="false"/>

    <executor-service name="default">
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
        <!--Queue capacity. 0 means Integer.MAX_VALUE.-->
        <queue-capacity>0</queue-capacity>
    </executor-service>

    <map name="userMap">
        <async-backup-count>1</async-backup-count>

        <near-cache>
            <max-size>5000</max-size>
            <invalidate-on-change>true</invalidate-on-change>
        </near-cache>

        <map-store enabled="false">
            <class-name></class-name>
            <write-delay-seconds>0</write-delay-seconds>
        </map-store>
    </map>

</hazelcast>
```

**Client code**

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new XmlClientConfigBuilder().build();  //the xml file is being loaded
HazelcastInstance hazelcastClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

I do not have a firewall running on my computer.  Any thoughts on what I may have misconfigured?

**Update:**
I am able to connect when i specify the ip address programmatically so I am assuming the issue is either with my client config or how I am readig it:

```
    ClientCOnfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("127.0.0.1");
    HazelcastInstance hcastClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by the following line in the client config xml file:

```
<security>
 <credentials>com.hazelcast.security.UsernamePasswordCredentials</credentials>
</security>
```

Once this was commented out, the client was able to connect to the server.  I will update once I gather more information regarding its usage.

Only seems to be available in enterprise edition, not the community one but ideally, it should have either let the connection establish or generate a meaningful error message.